# append a html include ng-click in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

i have this code in mycontroller i will add this `html()` to my html, all it right just ng-click dos not work ! have you an ideas why ng-click dos not work

```
 var html='<div ng-click="selectedValue('+Value+')">Value</div>' ;
     $('#myDiv').html(html);

   $scope.selectedValue = function(value){
     $scope.val =value;

  };
```

i have to slect the value displayed in the div by using ng-click function selectedValue

Answer (score 21, accepted):

use this code:

See [pluker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5kjo8u7Qiyw6KHFO1jkh?p=preview)

**Controller:**

```
var html='<div ng-click="selectedValue(value)">Value</div>',
    el = document.getElementById('myID');

$scope.value='mk';

angular.element(el).append( $compile(html)($scope) )

$scope.selectedValue = function (value) {
    $scope.val = value;
    console.log($scope.val)
};
```

**Html:**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div id="myID"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: @mukund : is there any way we can append html in angularjs service not in controller?

Answer (score 5):

You should do DOM manipulation through directive only, Ensure you need to compile element before injecting it.

**Code**

```
 var html='<div ng-click="selectedValue('+Value+')">Value</div>' ;
 angular.element(document.getElementByID('myDiv')).append($compile(html)(scope));
```

Comment: `.append` works with directive but not `.prepend` to add any div before matched div element.

Comment: True that. jQuery is already included. Any other alternate in Angular to prepend/inserBefore any element ? Also prepend is part of jqlite - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy my bad. then prepend should work as well

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39610194/angularjs-prepend-html-using-directive