# AngularJS: Prepend HTML using Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

**Service.js**

```
this.showSpinner = function (Id) {

    angular.element("<wave-spinner id='spinner00' ng-show='true'></wave-spinner>").remove();
    var myEl = angular.element(document.querySelector("#header00"))
    myEl.prepend($compile("<wave-spinner id='spinner00' ng-show='true'></wave-spinner>")($rootScope));
};
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="header00" style="">Some Content</div>
```

I tried using `prepend` method as mentioned in [jQlite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element), but its not working.

1. How do I show directive before div `header00`? .append works with
   directive but not .prepend to add any html content before matched div
   element.
2. When directive is called again, how do I remove existing html.
   `remove()` is not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code only needs a simple change. Switch the **before** function which does not exist to **prepend** ( You said that you have tried it but I'm sure this is the solution to this problem ).

```
myEl.prepend($compile("<wave-spinner id='spinner00' ng-show='true'></wave-spinner>")($rootScope));
```

To be sure I checked in jsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/maciejsikora/u5vLvxmx/

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
<wave-spinner id='spinner00' ng-show='isLoadingContent'></wave-spinner> 
<div id="header00" style="">Some Content</div>
```

and in service.js

```
 this.showSpinner = function () {
     this.isLoadingContent = true;
 };
```

Comment: wave-spinner will be prepend and I have shown final dom. Also how do I remove it first when user again performs the same action ?

Comment: if you want to have it not just hidden but not generated in html, then use ng-if instead of ng-show, the ng-if doesn't generate the element in the dom, the only trick is that it creates an additional inner scope. I would use a single method, and just negate the current value of `isLoadingContent` like this `this.isLoadingContent = !this.isLoadingContent;` and call the method in both cases when you need to show/hide.

Comment: `wave-spinner` will be prepend to div and not showing/hiding onload

Comment: Then I do't see any point in the `ng-show='true'` and your approach is more jQuery then angular approach. I don't really see why not have it in the html itself but have to append/prepend it. Please elaborate on why you stick to the approach you have?

Comment: Coz I want the directive to be called when user performs any action and not on page load

Comment: Let me understand - you want when user for example clicks on button x, to have appear this wave-spinner?

Comment: Now you are Correct

Comment: So then why you can't do this `<wave-spinner id='spinner00' ng-show='isLoadingContent'></wave-spinner> 
<div id="header00" style="">Some Content</div><input type="button" ng-click="showHideSpinner()"></input>` and in controller/service have this `this.isLoadingContent = false; this.showHideSpinner= function () {
     this.isLoadingContent = !this.isLoadingContent;
 };`