# How to use ng-repeat with quill editor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, quill

Hi im trying to use Quill editor js and use it with ng repeat. ( I got ng quill )
I need to use ng repeat .

This code return me error like:

quill Invalid Quill container #content245

quill Invalid Quill container #content244

quill Invalid Quill container #content243
....

I need your help !

```js
        $http.post("/getwallpost", reqGetPost).then(function(response) {
            var accounts = [];
            $scope.postsProfile = response.data
            
            for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; ++i) {
                if(response.data[i].type_id == 1) {
                     accounts[i] = new Quill("#content" + response.data[i].id + "", optionwall);
                     accounts[i].setContents(JSON.parse(response.data[i].content))
                     
                }
            }
        });
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="post in postsProfile" >
  <div class='postcontent' id='content{{post.id}}'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try adding an `ng-if` on the repeat

```
 $http.post("/getwallpost", reqGetPost).then(function(response) {
            var accounts = [];
            $scope.postsProfile = response.data

            for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; ++i) {
                if(response.data[i].type_id == 1) {
                     accounts[i] = new Quill("#content" + response.data[i].id + "", optionwall);
                     accounts[i].setContents(JSON.parse(response.data[i].content))

                }
            }
            $scope.showRepeat = true;
    });



<div ng-repeat="post in postsProfile" ng-if="showRepeat">
  <div class='postcontent' id='content{{post.id}}'></div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

could also be the opposite problem.

You should also try to call new Quill when printing the last repeat...

```
app.directive("lastRepeat", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, el, attrs){
            if(scope.$last){
                var eventId = "LR_";
                eventId += !!attrs.lastRepeat ? attrs.lastRepeat : "last";
                scope.$root.$broadcast(eventId);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

html

```
<div ng-repeat="post in postsProfile" ng-if="showRepeat" last-repeat="foo">
  <div class='postcontent' id='content{{post.id}}'></div>
</div>
```

and in your js...

```
 $scope.$root.on("LR_foo", function(){
          var data = angular.copy($scope.postsProfile);
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
                if(data[i].type_id == 1) {
                     accounts[i] = new Quill("#content" + data[i].id + "", optionwall);
                     accounts[i].setContents(JSON.parse(data[i].content))

                }
            }

 });

 $http.post("/getwallpost", reqGetPost).then(function(response) {
            var accounts = [];
            $scope.postsProfile = response.data


            $scope.showRepeat = true;
    });
```

Comment: didn't work in both ways, it says to me:
 $scope.$root is not a function

Answer (score 0):

I found other way to do this, cause it seem impossible to use ng-repeat with quill ( or I don't know the answer )
I used Jquery append function.
But you have to use the angularJS compiler ($compile) to compile the html

You can check more about that: 
[append a html include ng-click in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29925950/append-a-html-include-ng-click-in-angularjs)

it's simply and it works perfectly